# Cannot execute docker exec systemctl --user for a Docker container running systemd as PID=1?

Tags: linux, docker, containers, systemd, cgroups

If my container running (ENTRYPOINT aka PID 1) - `/lib/systemd/systemd systemd.unit=multi-user.service`, and also I have VOLUME ["/sys/fs/cgroup"] then why `docker exec -it --privileged systemctl --user` will display me `Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory`.

Is it possible to overcome that somehow?

Comment: Do you have dbus?

Comment: @AnyaShenanigans [dbus is pulled and installed as a dependency of systemd and user session bus is started automatically for each user](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/D-Bus)

Comment: @AnthonyGP: That might be true for a full Arch Linux installation where users go through the standard login process, but is it also true for your hand-crafted Docker container where the processes are just spawned directly? Have you **verified** that a user session bus is started for the user that's calling 'systemctl --user'?

Comment: This *seriously* doesn't have enough information to debug. There is no `multi-user.service` on stock linux (it's a target). docker exec *does not* properly start a new session. And this isn't a programming problem to be solved; it's more of a superuser problem

Comment: @AnyaShenanigans @user1686 when I run `docker run -it --privileged systemctl--user` then everything works fine and I got an output. So, still pending question, how I could execute that `systemctl` on running Docker container with systemd being an entrypoint?